# How can I maximize my turnip investment? Does it have price patterns?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

[New Leaf](https://animalcrossing.fandom.com/wiki/White_turnip) had pattern-based turnip pricing that could be used to predict when to buy and sell on the Stalk Market. Does New Horizon have any similar patterns for selling turnips in its weekly minigame?

Put another way, is there any way to predict how to maximize turnip investment, or is the pricing fluctuation just random?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few patterns that can occur which are outlined here: https://www.reddit.com/r/AnimalCrossing/comments/fr2cuq/guide_how_to_beat_the_stock_turnip_market_playing/

You might also be interested in this tool where you enter the prices and it will show your predicted prices https://elxris.github.io/Turnip-Calculator/

EDIT:

I want to add additional resources I've found since my first answer.

- [stalk.io](https://stalk.io) - tracking site which allows you to register and track prices over time, calculate how much you've made from stalks, and see friends' prices as they enter them
- [This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnimalCrossing/comments/fwmzac/how_we_believe_the_stalk_market_works_in_acnh_so/fmpqo63/) which goes into more details about what patterns are available for prices over a week, and the comments dive into the data dumps a bit.
- [turnip prophet](https://turnipprophet.io/index.html) - another tracking site that is a bit more data intensive than stalk.io. As the week goes on, it shows what price options could come up and how likely they are.